# getting parameter from default route

Tags: node.js, express

I am getting paramter from default route like this

conf.js: `router.use('/' ,require('./hello'));`

hello.js:

```
 router.get('/:param', async (req,res)=>{
    try{
       let { param }= req.params;
       console.log(param)
       let param = await Params.findOne({param});
       if(!param){
           return res.redirect('/not-found')
       }
  })
```

and when i visit to any url that i am handling or not handling (like this: `router.use('/blah',require('./blah'));`)
the code above handles it, so how can i prevent that and let the actual handler handle it? for example when i am redirected to /not-found this is actual /not-found handler

```
 router.get('/', async (req,res)=>{
     try{
         res.render('notfound')
     }catch(err){
        return res.redirect(url.format({
            pathname: '/error',
            query: {
                message: err.message
            }
        }))
     }
 })
```

but it is handled as `/:param`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express routes and middleware are order-dependent. Everying you add to `app` via `use`, `get`, `post`, etc. is actually one long chain of possible matches for the URL.

If the first route you add matches everything (at least, everything with only one path component) then sure enough, that route is going to match everything.

The solution is to add more specific routes like `app.get('/people')` first, and catch-alls like `app.get('/:param')` last.

As for the "not found" case however, I do not understand why you would expect this to fire at all. Of course any one-path-component path will match the `/:param` route. So perhaps what you really want is to match *only certain values of param*. For that, Express supports regex rules. There is a [good explanation here](https://www.kevinleary.net/regex-route-express/).

Answer (score 1):

if I understand you , you need to set this route `/:param` at the end of your routers chain

```
    router.use('/blah',require('./blah'))

  //then

 router.get('/:param', async (req,res)=>{
try{
   let { param }= req.params;
   console.log(param)
   let param = await Params.findOne({param});
   if(!param){
       return res.redirect('/not-found')
   }
})
```

so your request will arrive on the first route if it doesn't match it will go to the second one